# AJAX call to PHP file gets no response?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a really weird problem. I have the following form which exists in a modal:

```
<div id="regModal" class="modal regModal fade" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">


    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h2 class="modal-title text-center">Register</h2>

        </div>
        <form name='user-signup' method='post' id='user-signup'>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div id="modal-form-main-reg" class="modal-form-main">
                    <div class="error"></div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input class="form-control input-lg capt" id="f-name-modal" name="f-name"
                               placeholder="First Name"
                               type="text" required="required" spellcheck="false" maxlength="12"/>
                        <input class="form-control input-lg capt" id="l-name-modal" name="l-name" placeholder="Last Name"
                               type="text" required="required" spellcheck="false" maxlength="12"/>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input class="form-control input-lg" id="pwd_modal" name="pwd_modal"
                               placeholder="Password"
                               type="password" required="required" spellcheck="false" maxlength="12"/>
                        <input class="form-control input-lg" id="pwd_confirm_modal" name="pwd_confirm_modal"
                               placeholder="Confirm Password"
                               type="password" required="required" spellcheck="false" maxlength="12"/>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input class="form-control input-lg" id="subject" name="subject"
                               placeholder="Email address" type="text" required="required"
                               spellcheck="false" maxlength="30"/>
                        <input class="form-control input-lg" id="phone_no" name="phone_no"
                               placeholder="Phone No" type="text" required="required"
                               spellcheck="false" maxlength="14"/>
                    </div>
                </div>

                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input id="reg_worker_check" type="checkbox" value="">
                            <span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></span>
                            I'm registering as a (SP)
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group text-center">
                    <button id='usr_signup_btn' type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-next">CONTINUE</button>
                </div>
                <span class="reg-note">By registering, you agree to our <a href="#">Terms and Conditions</a>.</span>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <span class="ret-user">Returning user? <a href="/invercer/login">Login</a></span><span
                    class="need-help"><a
                        href="/invercer/blog">Need Help?</a></span>
            </div>
        </form>

        <script>
            $('#reg_worker_check').change(function(){
                if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                    $('form#user-signup').attr('action', 'signup').attr('method', 'get');
                } else {
                    $('form#user-signup').attr('action', '').attr('method', 'post');
                }
            });

            $("form#user-signup input").on("keydown", function (e) {
                return e.which !== 32;
            });

            $('form#user-signup input.capt').on('keydown', function(e) {
                if (this.value == '') {
                    var char = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
                    if (char.match(/^\w$/)) {
                        // If is empty and we pressed a printable key...
                        this.value = char.toUpperCase();
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            });
        </script>
    </div>

</div>
```

I have the following JS file (externally linked) which contains some jquery validation and is supposed to serialise the content posted from the form and send to "user-reg.php"

```
$(document).ready(function() {
/* validation */
$("#user-signup").validate({
    rules : {
        pwd_modal: {
            minlength: 6
        },
        pwd_confirm_modal: {
            minlength: 6,
            equalTo: "#pwd_modal"
        },
        subject: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        submitHandler: submitForm
    }
});

function submitForm() {
    var data = $("#user-signup").serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url  : 'user-reg.php',
        data : data,
        beforeSend: function() {
            $("#error").fadeOut();
            $("#usr_signup_btn").html("<span class='preloader-wrap'><img src='/invercer/img/preloader/103.gif' width='15' height='10' /></span> &nbsp; VERIFYING DATA ...");
        },
        success :  function(response) {
            if(response=="ok"){
                $("#usr_signup_btn").html("<span class='preloader-wrap'><img src='/invercer/img/preloader/103.gif' width='15' height='10' /></span> &nbsp; ADDING USER ...");
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $('#modal-form-main-reg').fadeOut('fast', function() {
                        $('#modal-form-main-reg').replace('<div class="modal-form-success-main text-center"><span>Registration successful!</span><br><br><a href="/login"><button class="form-control input-md">LOGIN PLEASE</button></a></div>').fadeIn('fast');
                    })
                }, 4000);
            }

            else if(response=="err") {
                $("#error").fadeIn(1000, function(){
                    $("#error").html('<div class="alert alert-danger"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> &nbsp; Registration error. Try again.</div>');
                        $("#usr_signup_btn").html('CONTINUE');
                });
            }

            else if(response=="crosscheck") {
                $("#error").fadeIn(1000, function(){
                    $("#error").html('<div class="alert alert-danger"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> &nbsp; Error. Please crosscheck what you typed.</div>');
                    $("#usr_signup_btn").html('CONTINUE');
                });
            }

            else{
                $("#error").fadeIn(1000, function(){
                    $("#error").html('<div class="alert alert-danger"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> &nbsp; '+response+' Unknown error!</div>');
                    $("#usr_signup_btn").html('CONTINUE');
                });
            }
        },
        error: function(response) {
            $("#error").fadeIn(1000, function(){
                $("#error").html('<div class="alert alert-danger"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> &nbsp; '+response+' Unknown error!</div>');
                $("#usr_signup_btn").html('CONTINUE');
            });
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

});

In user-reg.php, I have a series of DB calls and regular checks:

```
            <?php
            ob_start();

            session_start();

            error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

            require('app/functions.php');

            if(isset($_SESSION['user']) || isset($_SESSION['artisan'])) {
                header("Location: https://blabla.com");
            }

            else {

                if (isset($_POST['f-name']) && isset($_POST['l-name']) && (!isset($_SESSION['user']) && !isset($_SESSION['artisan']))) {
                    $f_name = sanitizeString($db, $_POST['f-name']);
                    $l_name = sanitizeString($db, $_POST['l-name']);
                    $email = sanitizeString($db, $_POST['subject']);
                    $tel = sanitizeString($db, $_POST['phone_no']);
                    $date = date('m-d-Y');

                    $key = true;
                    $usr_name = '';

                    while($key){
                        $usr_name = mt_rand(100000, 999999);
                        if(!compare_u($db, $usr_name)) $key = false;
                    }

                    $password = sanitizeString($db, $_POST['pwd_modal']);
                    $encrypted_password = encryptIt($password);

                    $query_sign_up = queryMysql($db, "INSERT INTO users VALUES('$usr_name', '$encrypted_password', '$f_name', '$l_name', '$email', '$tel', NULL, '$date')");
                    if($query_sign_up) echo "ok";
                    else echo "err";
                }
                else echo "crosscheck";
            }
```

The problem is, anytime I POST the form, it does not receive anything from user-reg.php. It doesn't even seem to see to the script. Consequently anytime I POST the form it keeps reloading the same page and not receiving ANYTHING via AJAX. On the JS file it works up to the validation section and nothing more. It's really funny cos I have another login script using this same technique that works perfectly. Validate.js and the other script are properly included in the header.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked the response code and text in the console to see exactly what is coming back?

Comment: It returns nothing to the console, instead it just reloads the page.

Comment: Try removing `return false;` from your `submitForm()` function

Comment: Is your script in `submitForm()` being called at all? If the page just reloads, it sounds like the native submit event is not prevented.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan return false doesn't work.

Comment: You mean removing it didn't change anything?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant

Comment: @AndFisher any ideas on how to disable native submit event? Tried `e.preventDefault();` just after the validation function but it didn't work.

Comment: Just discovered the bug. I was placing `submitHandler: submitForm` INSIDE the `rules` property. Sorry for wasting your time guys. Many thanks, and Merry Christmas :)

Answer (score 0):

It might not be executing the submitForm, try submitForm()

Comment: It's called from the `submitHandler` of the validate library.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I change to submitForm() but then it skips the validation and starts processing submitForm() on page load

Comment: It is interesting to note that this same js script structure works perfectly well in another login module in the codebase. For some reason it is not working with this particular form.

Comment: @DanielOsi - I think the problem is that validation isn't being called anywhere. I would try putting a breakpoint in your "submitForm" and seeing if it's even hitting it.

Comment: @PeterChon validation works on the form. I placed an alert inside submitForm()..didn't work.

Comment: @DanielOsi so it looks like submitForm isn't being called. try this:

Comment: `submitHandler: function() {
  submitForm();
}`

Comment: Just discovered the bug. I was placing `submitHandler: submitForm` INSIDE the `rules` property. Sorry for wasting your time guys. Many thanks, and Merry Christmas :)